# Button isn't disabling after I click it

Tags: c#, xaml, button, onclick

I have created a button that resets a textbox value to the default value, as shown:

```
<Button x:Name="DefaultButton"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Click="OnDefaultClicked">
```

Here is the `Click` method:

```
private void OnDefaultClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DefaultButton.IsEnabled = false;
    displayedData = defaultData;

    //rest of method code

}
```

When I click the button, the data resets to its default value automatically, but the button does not get disabled until I click it a second time. I am not sure why this is happening.

I could implement the `IsEnabled` property in the xaml code and bind it to a method that determines whether the button should be enabled based on the value of `displayedData`, but since the button is not re-enabled/disabled anywhere else in my application or used for any other purpose, this seems kind of like overkill... as far as I know, the `Click` event should be able to handle this alone. Regardless, my main problem is that I just don't understand why the button wouldn't get disabled until the 2nd click since the `OnDefaultClicked` method explicitly states it should be disabled when clicked.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this WPF, Xamarin, UWP, or what? Whatever it is, we need a [(minimal) reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to figure this out.

Comment: For what it's worth, in WPF, the code you posted disables the button on the first click. So the problem is in C# or XAML code that you didn't post.

Comment: Oh I figured it out! I looked back at my code for the textbox itself, and realized I had made it so that when the text changes, the button is re-enabled (so that the user can then reset it to default again if they want). So when you hit the default button, the text in the box changes and therefore both the ```OnTextChanged``` and ```OnDefaultClicked``` methods are triggered, which causes simultaneous enabling and disabling of the button, cancelling each other out. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the rest of my code. The snippet posted above worked perfectly fine. I realized I had created a method that re-enables the button when the text in the box changes, to allow the user to again reset it to default after making a change. So when the default button is clicked, the text in the box changes and therefore both the OnTextChanged and OnDefaultClicked methods are triggered, which causes simultaneous enabling and disabling of the button.

Here's how I fixed it:

```
private bool DefaultClicked;
private void OnDefaultClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DefaultButton.IsEnabled = false;
    DefaultClicked = true;
    displayedData = defaultData;

    //rest of method code

}
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!DefaultClicked)
    {
        DefaultButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    DefaultClicked = false;

    //rest of method code
}
```